# Show that the tangent only touches the graph in one point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be such that $f'$ is increasing. Show that for all $x$ the tangent line through the point $(x, f(x))$ only touches the graph in that point.

So I'm kinda stuck with this problem. I know that if $f'$ is increasing then $f''>0$ and I suppose I have to use that somehow. Maybe a mean value theorem? I don't know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ So the tangent line at $x_0$ is given by

$$y = f'(x_0) (x  - x_0) + f(x_0)$$

So you need to show that for all $x$, $f(x)> f'(x_0) (x  - x_0) + f(x_0)$.

Comment: yes but I don't know anything about f(x0) or about how x and x0 are related.

Comment: @Joan: What does mean value theorem tell you?

Comment: that there exists a c such that (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)=f'(c)

Comment: @Juan: If you try $a=x_0$ and $x = b$, what do you get?

Comment: that (f(x)-f(x0))/(x-x0)>f'(x0)

Comment: @Juan: There's no inequality sign in mean value theorem!

Comment: ok ok ... (f(x)-f(x0))/(x-x0)=f'(c)

Comment: @Juan: So can you use this one to see why the inequality in my answer is true?

Comment: if my interval is [x0, x] then any c in it will be such that f'(c)>f'(x0) because f' is increasing, right?

Comment: @Juan: I think you mean $f'(c)> f'(x)$ if you interval is $[x, x_0]$, as $c> x$.